# Double Factorial: Number of possibilities to partition a set of $2n$ items into $n$ pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the partition of $2n$ items into $n$ pairs has something to do with double factorial, but I am not sure how many possibilities we exactly have.

We can choose such a partition into pairs by first choosing $n$ elements to be in one half and the remaining $n$ in the other half, which gives ${{2n} \choose n}$ possibilities. Then we can take a permutation of both sets and match them accordingly.

This gives $${{2n} \choose n} n! n!=\frac{(2n)! n! n!}{n! n!}=(2n)!$$ possibilities. But with this we overcount, since we do not want the pairs to be ordered. Each of the $n$ pairs is counted twice, wherefore we have to divide by 2 for every pair, hence $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$?

Well, another possiblity to do that is just to iteratively pick $2$ elements among the remaining ones, which gives ${{2n} \choose 2} {{2n-2} \choose 2} \dotsb {4 \choose 2}$

I am not sure, but I do not think that this is the same and also, I do not see the connection to double factorial. Would be very glad if you could help me with these 3 possiblities.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\binom{2n}{n}n!n!$ overcounts in two ways -- first, as you notice, because it cares about the order *within* the pairs; second because it distinguishes *which pair appears where* in the final list of pairs.

So this way of counting gives you a way of counting ways to arrange the $2n$ elements such that there's a definite answer to "what is the second element of the 17th pair?", which means that each element has a definite place. When the dust settles, what you've done is just to count the number of ways to arrange $2n$ elements in $2n$ individually named positions -- thus $(2n)!$.

Your second way of counting repairs the *first* problem but not the second.

One way to get the right answer would be to correct the first one for *both* kind of overcounting, giving
$$ \frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n} $$
where the $n!$ in the denominator corrects for reordering the pairs themselves, and $2^n$ corrects for possibly swapping the elements of each pair.

Another way would be to say: As long as there are still unpaired elements left, take the *lowest-numbered* of those remaining, and select one of the rest to pair it with. This gives
$$ (2n-1)(2n-3)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1 = (2n-1)!!$$
possibilites.

---

Bonus exercise: Argue symbolically that $\frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n}=(2n-1)!!$.

Comment: attempt to Answer the bonus exercise: We have $(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}= \frac{(2n)!}{(2n) (2n-2) (2n-4) \dotsb 4 \cdot 2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2(n) 2(n-1) 2(n-2) \dotsb (2 \cdot 2) (2 \cdot 1)} =\frac{(2n)!}{ 2^{n} n!}$. I think, this should be correct, but I am quite unsure with this type of calculations!
By the way: Thank you very much for your help. This explains a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Number the items $1$ through $2n$. There are $2n-1$ ways to choose an item to be paired with item $1$. Let $a$ be the remaining item with the smallest number; there are $2n-3$ possible choices for the item to be paired with $a$. Continuing in this fashion, we find that the entire pairing can be made in $(2n-1)!!$ different ways. To see how this compares with your attempts, note that

$$(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\;,$$

since

$$(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\ldots(4)(2)=2^ nn!\;.$$

In particular, your last attempt is too large by a factor of $n!$: you need to divide by $n!$ to account for the different orders in which a given pairing can be chosen.