# How to partition $nk$ objects $\frac{1}{n}\binom{nk}{k}$ times, each time making subsets of size $k$, so that no combination of $k$ is repeated.

Tags: algorithms, permutations, combinations, cyclic-groups, set-partition

What is an algorithm to partition $nk$ objects a total of $\frac{1}{n}\binom{nk}{k}$ times, each time making subsets of size exactly $k$, so that no subset of size $k$ is ever repeated?

For example, if $n=k=3$, then we have $9$ objects and we want to partition into groups of size $3$. We must hit all $\binom{9}{3}=84$ combinations in $\frac{1}{3}\binom{9}{3}=28$ partitions. For this example, the naive approach of iterating through all permutations in order and greedily choosing the first ones that work (as shown below) does not suffice; it can hit only $72$ of the $84$ combinations.

$[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)],
[(0, 1, 3), (2, 4, 6), (5, 7, 8)],
[(0, 1, 4), (2, 3, 7), (5, 6, 8)],
[(0, 1, 5), (2, 3, 6), (4, 7, 8)],
[(0, 1, 6), (2, 3, 8), (4, 5, 7)],
[(0, 1, 7), (2, 3, 5), (4, 6, 8)],
[(0, 1, 8), (2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7)],
[(0, 2, 3), (1, 5, 8), (4, 6, 7)],
[(0, 2, 4), (1, 5, 6), (3, 7, 8)],
[(0, 2, 5), (1, 4, 7), (3, 6, 8)],
[(0, 2, 6), (1, 3, 7), (4, 5, 8)],
[(0, 2, 7), (1, 3, 8), (4, 5, 6)],
[(0, 2, 8), (1, 4, 5), (3, 6, 7)],
[(0, 3, 4), (1, 5, 7), (2, 6, 8)],
[(0, 3, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 7, 8)],
[(0, 3, 6), (1, 4, 8), (2, 5, 7)],
[(0, 3, 7), (1, 6, 8), (2, 4, 5)],
[(0, 4, 6), (1, 2, 7), (3, 5, 8)],
[(0, 4, 7), (1, 2, 8), (3, 5, 6)],
[(0, 4, 8), (1, 2, 6), (3, 5, 7)],
[(0, 5, 7), (1, 3, 6), (2, 4, 8)],
[(0, 5, 8), (1, 3, 4), (2, 6, 7)],
[(0, 6, 7), (1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 8)],
[(0, 6, 8), (1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 7)]$

Basically, this is equivalent to [Efficiently partition a set into all possible unique pair combinations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477767/efficiently-partition-a-set-into-all-possible-unique-pair-combinations), but instead of partitioning into pairs, I am partitioning into subsets of size $k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The existence of a solution is guaranteed by [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai's_theorem). A proof of the theorem can be found, for instance, in [Dieter Jungnickel - Graphs, Networks and Algorithms](https://books.google.nl/books?id=NvuFAglxaJkC&pg=PA231&lpg=PA231&dq=baranyai+theorem+algorithm&source=bl&ots=GLv0ZIO7pn). The proof is constructive, so an algorithm can be derived from it. The book I mention contains references for explicit constructions in certain special cases.

Furthermore, [a Python implementation is given on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902878). I cannot attest to its correctness.