# Probability a woman is paired with her husband

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$2n$ people consisting of $n$ couples are randomly paired together. What is the probability that a particular woman gets paired with her husband?

I know that the answer is $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ because a woman is equally likely to be paired with any of the other $2n-1$ people that are not her, and only one of them is her husband. However, when I first tried to solve this problem, I tried the following:

There are $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$ possible ways of making the $n$ couples. Likewise, there should be $\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}}$ ways of coupling all the $2n-2$ people that are not the particular woman and her husband. Therefore, the probability of the woman getting paired with her husband should be $\frac{1}{n(2n-1)}$.

My question is: why am I getting this extra $n$ term in the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the problem: say for example $n=3$.  Put the people in some predetermined order (say, alphabetical order), and label them with numbers for each couple.  So for example
$$123321$$
means the first person goes with the last, the second with the second last and the third with the third last.  However, your $(2n)!/2^n$ ways of forming couples also include, for example,
$$321123\ ,$$
which is actually the same arrangement of couples.  The correct number of ways of forming couples is
$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!}$$
and then your probability calculation is
$$\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-1}\,(n-1)!}\bigg/\frac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!}
  =\frac1{2n-1}\ .$$

Comment: And as a further reference, the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058972/double-factorial-number-of-possibilities-to-partition-a-set-of-2n-items-into) give a couple of explanations of the expression for the number of ways to form the couples.

Comment: So I am overcounting because I take into account the order of the pairs?

Comment: That's correct.